# Document won't save after selecting value combobox

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpage with 3 comboboxes related to each other.
In the onchange event of Combobox1 I have a partial refresh of combobox2(since the key of the dblookup of combobox2 is the  value of combobox1). As server option I have "Do not validate or update data"
Same for combobox2 and 3.
Then I have a button that will pick up the submitted values of the comboboxes , and saves a document with these values.
The problem : when I pick up a value for combobox1 and click on the "Save"button a document is saved .
When I click on the second and also the third button, I can't save a document anymore ...
I don't get any error message either.
edit ;
Simplified version of the code :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="bestelbon"></xp :dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>`

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" value="#{sessionScope.item}">
                                            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Please select">
                                            </xp:selectItem><xp:selectItems id="selectItems2">
                                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbColumn("product/Bestelbon.nsf","item",1));    
}]]></xp:this.value>
                                            </xp:selectItems>
                                            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="comboBox2" immediate="true">
                                            </xp:eventHandler>


                                        </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="comboBox2" value="#{sessionScope.subitem}">

                                            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Please select">
                                            </xp:selectItem>
                                            <xp:selectItems id="selectItems3">
                                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var combo1 = getComponent("comboBox1").getSubmittedValue();
@Unique(@DbLookup("product/Bestelbon.nsf","subitem2",combo1,2));
}]]></xp:this.value>
                                            </xp:selectItems>
                                            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="comboBox3" immediate="true">
                                            </xp:eventHandler>
                                        </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="comboBox3" value="#{sessionScope.subsubitem}">
                                            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Please select">
                                            </xp:selectItem>
                                            <xp:selectItems id="selectItems4">
                                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var combo1 = getComponent("comboBox2").getSubmittedValue();
@Unique(@DbLookup("product/Bestelbon.nsf","subsubitem2",combo1,2));
}]]></xp:this.value>
                                            </xp:selectItems>
                                        </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="comboBox4" value="#{sessionScope.optie}" defaultValue="Gratis optie">
                                        <xp:selectItems>
                                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbColumn("product/Bestelbon.nsf","mogelijkheid",1));}]]></xp:this.value>
                                        </xp:selectItems>
                                    </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="comboBox5" value="#{sessionScope.combinatie}">
                                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Please select">
                                        </xp:selectItem>
                                        <xp:selectItems>
                                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbColumn("product/Bestelbon.nsf","subsubitem",1));}]]></xp:this.value>
                                        </xp:selectItems>
                                    </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button id="button1" value="Save">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var combo1 = getComponent("comboBox1")
var value1= combo1.getSubmittedValue();
if (null == value1){
value1 = combo1.getValue();
}
var combo2 = getComponent("comboBox2")
var value2= combo2.getSubmittedValue();
if (null == value2){
value2 = combo1.getValue();
}
var combo3 = getComponent("comboBox3")
var value3= combo3.getSubmittedValue();
if (null == value3){
value3 = combo3.getValue();
}
var combo4 = getComponent("comboBox4")
var value4= combo4.getSubmittedValue();
if (null == value4){
value4 = combo4.getValue();
}
var combo5 = getComponent("comboBox5")
var value5= combo5.getSubmittedValue();
if (null == value5){
value5 = combo5.getValue();
}
document1.replaceItemValue("bbitem",value1);
document1.replaceItemValue("bbpsubitem",value2);
document1.replaceItemValue("bbsubsubitem",value3);
document1.replaceItemValue("bbmogelijkheid",value4);
document1.replaceItemValue("bbopmerking",value5);
document1.replaceItemValue("bbland","VF");
document1.replaceItemValue("bbproduct","NAVIX");
document1.save();
}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button></xp:view>
```

Comment: are you sure document is not saved? or it is saved without proper combo values (I suppose)? check last update and let me know. I think "Do not validate or update data" is the problem - it does not submit values to datasource.

Comment: The document isn't saved. I've put fixed values in order to be sure there was something to be saved. Once you click on more than one of those comboboxes nothing will be saved anymore. If you click on only one combobox the document will be saved. Seems like a bug to me , but I don't know how to go around it ... By the way I'm using 8.5.3

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the submitted values you must use `getComponent("comboBoxX").getSubmittedValue()` (instead of .getValue() ).

I need more details of the data source in order to understand why you are unable to save. But try using .getSubmittedValue() and see if that helps you.

Comment: I tried getSubmittedvalue, which doesn't give me a value ; getValue does. The datasource document1 is just a form in that same nsf file. Nothing special. I guess the problem is somewhere with the "Do not validate or update data" of the combo boxes...

Comment: Why do you use "Do not validate or update data" on combobox 2 and 3? That means that data are not updated - hence you can get their value using server-side JS. So remove that option. If you want to avoid any validation of data on onChange then use "Process data without validation" instead.

Comment: The values of combobox2 depend on your choice of combobox1. And the choices of combobox3 depend on what you selected in combobox2. When I select "Process data without validation" for combobox2, I don't get any values in my combobox3. For combobox3 I didn't put an onchange event.  Not necessary.

Comment: And you have an onChange event in combobox2 that partially refreshes combobox3? Can you update your question with all your code? It makes it much easier to help.

Comment: I also tried following:
I've put the data fields to a page with a Submit button.
Then I made a Panel with the 3 combo boxes.
I didn't relate them in any way.
When you fill in the edit boxes and click Submit , it saves the document.
When you fill in the edit boxes , and then select values in the comboboxes and then click Submit , nothing will be saved.

Comment: When you fill in the edit boxes and select a value only in the first combobox and click Submit , it saves !!
I guess there is a problem of focus on the fields.

Comment: When you put the 3 comboboxes in a Panel, and then fill  out the necessary fields, and then choose the correct values of the comboboxes and refresh the Panel in which the comboxes reside not 1 but 2 times , the document will be saved after the submit. Problem now is how do I make that work in SSJS (getting the combobox value the rerfesh 2 times and then save the document) ...